# How to reverse the point order of a CGPath

Tags: ios, core-text, cgpath, cashapelayer

I want to draw a Circle with Letter punched out of it. to do this, I need to stroke the circle clockwise and the letter counterclockwise.

That is all good and well, but when I get the letter path using Core Text I can't figure out how to essentially reverse the path. NOT MIRROR or ROTATE or anything...that is straightforward enough. I want the point stroke order to be counterclockwise.

it is actually hilariously difficult. I've had entirely too many visual 'off by one' errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS 6 introduced `-bezierPathByReversingPath`
It had some issues at first but it seems to be the answer to this question.

Comment: Still not ideal if you want iOS 5 support though.

Comment: True, but I imagine support for iOS 5 will begin a faster decline in the coming months.

Answer (score 3):

About all I can think of is to call [CGPathApply](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPath/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPathApply) on the path and save information about all of the points, and then redraw the path in the opposite direction. Remember to call `CGPathCloseSubpath` when you're done.

Comment: Thanks to some help, I can get all of the points... I'll forge ahead I suppose.